# Qt, MSVC, Suppress compiler warning in a moc_

Tags: qt, visual-c++, moc

I've just started using MSVC with Qt. While compiling a moc_, MSCV is generating
a warning -

"warning C4251: 'QBasicMutex::d_ptr': class 'QBasicAtomicPointer' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'QBasicMutex'

In my own source code I can use :-

```
  #pragma warning ( push )
  #pragma warning ( disable : 4251 )
  #include <QApplication>
  #pragma warning ( pop )
```

when I include a Qt header, which appears to work, but I can't get it to work with a moc_.

How do I:-

1. Suppress that warning
2. Or failing that, turn down the general warning level in MSVC so this warning (and unfortunately any others) are suppressed

I'm using Qt 5.15.2, with MSVC 2019

Thanks.

Comment: Add '/wd4251' to your compiler flags

Comment: @chehrlic Thanks, that worked. To be specific:-  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /wd4251 in the .pro file

Comment: @PeteD. If you got an answer then post it in the answers section, do not add it to your post as an edit. Please read [ask] and [answer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add '/wd4251' to your compiler flags (qmake: QMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, cmake: target_compile_definitions)